# Is it possible to trip a bulette?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, prone

Tripping and the prone condition, in general, are rather easy to manage. You are prone? Well your enemies have an advantage on their melee attack and a disadvantage on ranged attacks, plus, you can only crawl or get up using half of your movement. When you trip someone, if they fail their save check, they are knocked prone. So far, so good.

What puzzles me is when you are attempting to trip a creature that, by its shape, looks technically already "prone", or rather looks like being tripped wouldn't make much of a difference. A bulette is a creature that comes to my mind, along with crocodiles and giant crabs.

I tried to look it up, but couldn't find any rule suggesting there would be an exception regarding the shape of the targetted creature, nor could I find any creature trait that would prevent them from being prone or tripped. The way I am describing it right now is that in such cases, the creature would be rolling on its back, or fall on the side, whichever makes sense. The rules remain the same:

- the creatures makes the saving throw against the shove or the tripping attack
- the creature moves at half its speed until it "rolls over" to get up.
- Advantages for melee attacks against the creature and Disadvantages for the creature and ranged attackers.

Is this a correct way to manage the prone condition for those creatures? Is there an actually official way to do it?

Comment: Related, in a sense: "[What happens when a swimming creature falls prone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111104)"

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, that question asks about snakes, but it seems to be the same issue, and it has an *exceptionally* well received answer. Let us know if that doesn’t solve your problem.

Comment: @thomas-markov wow thank you so much! I can't believe I failed to find that one.

Comment: I’ll take that as a “that solves it”. You probably already know this as you’ve been around a bit, but I’ll mention it anyway: duplicate closures are okay! They can can help others find answers that are sometimes harder to find with the search bar. The next person who has this question is now more likely to find the post about snakes thanks to you.