# If I'm invisible and use stealth, but the enemy has See Invisibility, what can I do without being detected?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, stealth, invisibility

I'm preparing for a large encounter in my campaign. Unfortunately, the DM likes to be a jerk to me when I try to do something spectacular, such as casting *darkness* over an area of enemies and then telling me the sword someone is using is shedding a magical light that dispels all that darkness.

So I need to be prepared.

I'm a level 5 shadow monk. I will be using Dust of Disappearance, a Cloak of Elvenkind, and the Pass without Trace spell before an encounter to gain advantage; however, I was informed that one enemy, if not multiple enemies, will have *see invisibility*.

**Even though they have *see invisibility*, will they be able to see me if I get, say, an average roll of 27 on Dexterity (stealth) with bonuses?** Could I, say, walk into the center of the opening without getting caught, or do I have to be obscured to remain undetected?

What is the limit of what I can do without being detected?

I'm playing D&D 5th edition, in the *Out of the Abyss* campaign.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Related: [Do you need to take the Hide action when you are Invisible, make no noise and leave no traces?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86945/do-you-need-to-take-the-hide-action-when-you-are-invisible-make-no-noise-and-le), [Is hiding different when invisible than when behind total cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127346/is-hiding-different-when-invisible-than-when-behind-total-cover), [What happens when an invisible creature is detected?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47727/what-happens-when-an-invisible-creature-is-detected)

Answer (score 6):

### You can do the same things you could do without invisibility.

The relevant effect of *see invisibility* is:

> you see invisible creatures and objects as if they were visible

This means that your invisibility has no effect with regard to any enemies that cast this spell, and any stealthy actions you attempt will be governed by stealth and perception rolls are normal. If you've reached level 5 playing a sneaky character, you should have a pretty good idea by now of how your DM handles stealth rolls. Expect them to handle them exactly the same here, since your invisibility confers no benefit against enemies that cast *see invisibility*.

### Rolling stealth means you're trying to be stealthy

When you roll a Dexterity (stealth) check, you do so because you are attempting to hide or otherwise avoid drawing attention to yourself. Walking out in the open is the opposite of that. **If you're not attempting to stay hidden, you shouldn't expect any benefit from your stealth check,** no matter how high you roll. This is where invisibility would help you: if you're invisible, you *can* hide out in the open (unless your enemies can see invisibility, of course).

Answer (score 3):

## Depends on if they're looking at you

See Invisibility effectively nullifies the effects of your invisibility for the creatures with the trait. At that point, you would contest their passive perception with your stealth roll if they're unaware of your presence. If you were to roll a 27 on a Dexterity (Stealth) check and attempt to walk directly in front of someone, you would likely be discovered unless the DM were to narrate something drawing their attention away from you in that moment.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check the [help] for more guidance. Good answer!